# Nested macros in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define A(int x) printf("%d\n",x)
#define AS(A) A(20)
typedef struct{
 int *m;
 int n;
 int k;
}st;
//static st sb[10] = {AS(A)}
int main()
{
    AS(A);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting an error as below .

```
Line 14: error: macro parameters must be comma-separated
```

Please help.

Comment: Thanks all for making me to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with nesting macros. The problem is

```
#define A(int x) printf("%d\n",x)
```

you must remove the `int` part. Like this:

```
#define A(x) printf("%d\n",x)
```

---

If you leave the `int`, the preprocessor interprets it as another parameter, that's why it tells you

```
Line 14: error: macro parameters must be comma-separated
```

because expects:

```
#define A(int,x) printf("%d\n",x)
```

Answer (score 3):

***In C, macro parameters aren't typed. It's all symbol substitution*** . Try this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define A(x) printf("%d\n",x) /*Remove the type */
#define AS(A) A(20)
int main()
{
    AS(A);
    return 0;
}
```

see [codepad](http://codepad.org/CHjvyK2s)

Answer (score 2):

You dont actually need this : `#define A(int x) printf("%d\n",x)`

but you need : `#define A(x) printf("%d\n",x)` , you don't actually need to declare a variable in preprocessor! ,

`Note that :` The preprocessor does not know anything about keywords.